# Cent OS 6.3 Hidden files in shell

Tags: linux, shell, files, xattr, verification

I want to be able to check whether a file is hidden or not in Cent OS 6.3. These are often referred to as (dot) files but I can clearly see Cent OS 6.3 handling these by appending a ~(tilde) to the end

EG:

myfile (not hidden)
myfile~ (hidden)

Now, I can tell that a file is "hidden" if it's a dot file, but what is going on with this tilde (~) terminating character - is this particular to Cent OS 6.3? Is this something I can simply check for in the file name (EG: starting with a  dot or ending with a tilde) I would appreciate help on this as, I would assume "hidden" is a file attribute rather than a "naming convention" as I wrong?

Comment: There is no “hidden” file attribute, any hiding is done by the software listing the files. So which program are you using that's hiding files?

Comment: Is this for tab completion inside the bash shell?  If so, check the value of the `FIGNORE` variable using `echo $FIGNORE`.

Comment: they are "hidden" in nautilus ("show hidden files")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tilde suffix marks a backup file for a few text editors, such as Emacs ('~') and Vim ('.ext~').

Some programs hide these files, as most people don't care about them.

The only universal convention for a 'hidden' file is a file with a leading '.', due to [a feature-like bug](https://plus.google.com/101960720994009339267/posts/R58WgWwN9jp) which was widely adopted.

Comment: thanks for the link - I suspected it was some kind of "retcon" _ I am syncing files and I want to ignore locked files, hidden files etc so thanks for the info